# Browser hangs when trying to load a page from flask app

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm building a web app that lists artists, venues, and shows.  When the user clicks on a venue in the list, it should take them to that venue's page.  Instead, it just hangs.  It never moves from the venue listing page, the loading bar in the browser starts loading but hangs at like 15-20%.  No error is returned, I've waited it out a few minutes but it just doesn't move.

I'm posting the route code, but you can also check out the [Github repo](https://github.com/zemelb/fyyurr) for the full code in case it's necessary.

```
@app.route('/venues/<int:venue_id>')
def show_venue(venue_id):
  # shows the venue page with the given venue_id
  # TODO: replace with real venue data from the venues table, using venue_id
  # NOT WORKING YET
  
  # query db for the venue's ID
  venuequery = Venue.query.get(venue_id)

  # if it finds a venue with that ID
  if venuequery:
    venue_details = Venue

    data = {
      "id": venue_details.id, 
      "name": venue_details.name, 
      "genres": venue_details.genres, 
      "addres": venue_details.address, 
      "city": venue_details.city, 
      "state": venue_details.state, 
      "phone": venue_details.phone, 
      "website": venue_details.website, 
      "facebook_link": venue_details.facebook_link, 
      "seeking_talent": venue_details.seeking_talent, 
      "seeking_description": venue_details.seeking_description, 
      "image_link": venue_details.image_link, 
      }
     return render_template('pages/show_venue.html', venue=data)
```

Edit: When I add `print(data)` before the `return`, this is what prints:

```
{'id': <sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute object at 0x7f83904780e0>, 'name': <sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute object at 0x7f8390478180>, 'genres': <sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute object at 0x7f83904784a0>, 'addres': <sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute object at 0x7f8390478360>, 'city': <sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute object at 0x7f8390478220>, 'state': <sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute object at 0x7f83904782c0>, 'phone': <sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute object at 0x7f8390478400>, 'website': <sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute object at 0x7f8390478680>, 'facebook_link': <sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute object at 0x7f83904785e0>, 'seeking_talent': <sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute object at 0x7f8390478720>, 'seeking_description': <sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute object at 0x7f83904787c0>, 'image_link': <sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute object at 0x7f8390478540>}
```

Comment: let say you want to access first venue from the db. can you send me the value of venuquery and could you please print the data before return statement. I would like to be sure that you are constructing data correctly.

Comment: @cagta edited the post to include what's printed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
# if it finds a venue with that ID
  if venuequery:
    venue_details = venuequery          # Pass class object instead of class itself
```

instead of this

```
# if it finds a venue with that ID
  if venuequery:
    venue_details = Venue
```